# Javascript idiom for code structure

Tags: javascript, idioms

My javascript gets included multiple times with the script tag, like so:

```
<script src="code.js></script>
<script src="code.js></script>
<script src="code.js></script>
```

Right now I have this code inside **code.js** to make my code run only once without overwriting my namespaces:

```
if(typeof _ow == "undefined" ){
_ow = {};
// code in here will only run once

_ow.Auth = (function(){
})();
_ow.Template = (function(){
})();

}
```

Is there any better structure I could use to make my code only run once?

Comment: Um... why is your code.js getting included multiple times?

Comment: Honesty, what you have *is* the JavaScript idiom for this. It's also the most readable way of doing it. No need to be too clever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with Crockford's [Javascript Module Pattern](http://ajaxian.com/archives/a-javascript-module-pattern)?

A slight variation on how to prevent overwriting the namespace:

```
var _ow;
if(!_ow) _ow = {};
```

Comment: How would that code snippet work? When re-executing that piece of code it will re-define **_ow** everytime.

Comment: var _ow = 9; var _ow; assert(_ow === 9) //true

Answer (score 2):

```
var _ow = _ow || { Auth: ... };
```

if its already defined then it wont be defined again.

Comment: Yes I was doing something like that, but then I would need to do that for all my "functions", like _ow.Auth = _ow.Auth || (function(){})(); which isn't exactly nice.

Comment: you only have to do it once for _ow

Comment: you don't have to do it multiple times for each function, just once with you create the _ow variable

Answer (score 1):

While what you are doing will technically work, it is inefficient, because even though your code only gets run once, it does end up being parsed a number of times on some browsers (this is different than downloading a file via the network, and cannot be cached).

It is best to ensure that the script only gets included once. For all the repeated functionality you can expose a function to be called whenever needed.